# 'Cannot read property of undefined' trying to access a specific element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following block of code for a class declaration:

```
class Node {
   constructor(alias, statement, additionalInformation, source) {
      this.id;
      this.alias = alias;
      this.statement = statement;
      this.additionalInformation = additionalInformation;
      this.source = source;
      this.getInfo = getNodeInfo;
      }
}
```

And I have this piece of code in order to populate an array of Node Objects:

```
var arrNodes = [];
var i = 0;

$.getJSON('source.json', function(data){
   $(data.nodes).each(function (index,value) {
   arrNodes.push(new Node(value.alias, value.statement,value.additionalInformation, value.source));
   console.log(arrNodes[i].alias, arrNodes[i].statement, arrNodes[i].source);
   i++;
   });
});
```

And until this moment everything worked well, I am able to get those values that I logged from a console. But every time I'm trying to access any array element separately, let's say like this:

```
console.log(arrNodes[0].alias);
```

I get the following this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alias' of undefined
```

Could you help me to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting data back from your JSON call before you access the array on the console?

Comment: @n8wrl This happens even if i'm trying to reach a single element within this block:

$.getJSON('source.json', function(data){});

Right after populating the array.

Comment: @n8wrl Well, perhaps I am not. I tried to get an array length in a console right after $.getJSON() and I got 0. Only afterwards I get all arrNodes values in the console. I think I don't get the sequence of the running code here.